# Use of chaining OngoingStubbing Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

In Mockito when we try to mock a method call, let's say we configure something like this

```
when(exampleClass.getOutputString(anyString())).thenReturn("output1");
```

This is all understandable. But my question is what is the reason this `thenReturn("output1")` method returns an OngoingStrubbing object (same as what `when(exampleClass.getOutputString(anyString()))` method returns), so that we can do something like this

```
when(exampleClass.getOutputString(anyString())).thenReturn("output1").thenReturn("output2");
```

or

```
when(exampleClass.getOutputString(anyString())).thenReturn("output1").thenThrow(new IllegalArgumentException());
```

However, both the above cases, when using the mock, it only returns `"output1"` and that's all the story. Anyone knows, why this chaining feature is present, and what are the uses of it? Kind of same thing applies to `doReturn()` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means for the first call gives `ouput1` and in the second call gives `output2`, and so on.

```
when(exampleClass.getOutputString(anyString())).thenReturn("output1").thenReturn("output2");
```

, The second one you need to reach one condition in the target test class so gives

`output1` for the first case but in the second one you want to fail to test for example

try-catch clause or see if the code cover the broken scenarios like exceptions

```
when(exampleClass.getOutputString(anyString())).thenReturn("output1").thenThrow(new IllegalArgumentException());
```